# Jquery only registers one id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three checkboxes that looks like this:

```
<input id="image_tagging" class="1" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="data[image_tagging]">
```

now i wanted to create some ajax (which is working fine) however only the first checkbox has the event:

here is my Jquery function:

```
    $('#image_tagging').click(function(){
    var value = 0;
    var websiteID = $(this).attr('class');
    if($(this).attr('checked')){
        value = 4;
    }else{
        value = -4;
    }
    alert('works! '+'id = '+websiteID+" value = "+value );
});
```

So my question is. why is this click function only happening for one of my checkboxes? (if it matters it is only the first checkbox that is working)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with your code but what if you tried using class instead of ID?

Comment: If all have the same id how will it work, try changing the id's as they need to be unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id`s must be unique on an html page. Instead use a class in the markup and a class selector in jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<input class="image_tagging 1" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="data[image_tagging]">
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.image_tagging').click(function(){
    var value = 0;
    var websiteID = $(this).attr('class');
    if($(this).attr('checked')){
        value = 4;
    }else{
        value = -4;
    }
    alert('works! '+'id = '+websiteID+" value = "+value );
});
```

Answer (score 3):

IDs have to be unique change the id to class instead

```
id="image_tagging"
```

to

```
class="image_tagging"
```

then

```
  $('.image_tagging').click(function(){
```

Answer (score 1):

**in html**

```
<input class="image_tagging" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="data[image_tagging]">
```

**in js**

```
 $('.image_tagging').click(function(){ 
// your code

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`id` must be unique, use class instead or try this...

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    var value = 0;
    var websiteID = $(this).attr('class');
    if($(this).attr('checked')){
        value = 4;
    }else{
        value = -4;
    }
    alert('works! '+'id = '+websiteID+" value = "+value );
});
```

no need to change any `HTML` code you wrote already...

Answer (score 0):

`ID` should be unique in your DOM structure. Use `class` instead of ID for such things.

```
<input id="image_tagging" class="img_tagging 1" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="data[image_tagging]">
```

And then instead of `#image_tagging`  use `.image_tagging` for binding click event

```
$('.image_tagging').click(function(){
```